# what is the difference between "yet" and "still"?

Tags: meaning, difference, adverbs

what is the difference between "yet" and "still"?

When we can use "still"? and when we can use "yet"?

Are they synonyms or not?

"The plan could yet succeed." Can I use "still" in that sentence instead of "yet"?

"I still don't understand." Can I use "yet" in that sentence too?

Comment: [Relevant](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/935/understanding-still-and-yet-usage)

Comment: Is your father up yet? - No, he's still in bed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In their closest meanings, "still" is used for a situation that is ongoing or unchanged at any point in time, or regardless of any factor, stated or otherwise:

> She **still** loves you. If you lose all your money, she will **still** love
>   you. Even when you were abusive, she **still** loved you.

"yet" has a similar interpretation, but describes the state of a something, within a process, at any given time within a progression, up to that point in a process:

> He is **yet** a child. -*or*- He is a child **yet**.
>
> He's **still** a child.

In another usage, it is closer to "already." In questions, it asks whether something has happened "already" or up to the time of questioning, and additionally implies that the addressee is expected or required to do it:

> Have you called your mother **yet**?

Here the speaker possibly commanded or just expects the addressee call his mother, or was informed of the his intention to call his mother, and is questioning whether he has done it. "Already" doesn't have this force - it merely questions the completion of the action logistically:

Have you already called your mother? I wanted to say hello to her. (=Am I too late?)

Note that the idiom "have yet to" is used with the above meaning to express that something expected still hasn't been done:

He has **yet** to call his mother. (= He's supposed to do it, but hasn't done it.)

I have yet to see that movie. (= I've been meaning to see it, but haven't gotten around to it.)

"Not yet" - or "yet" in any negative context - is the opposite of "already:"

> My father **already** sent me a birthday present.
>
> My father **hasn't** sent me a birthday present **yet**.

Finally, "yet" can function as a conjunction like "but, however" that emphasizes a result obtained or a situation that arises despite certain factor(s):

> He's only been speaking English for a year, **yet** he sounds just like an
>   American.
>
> I've asked you a million times not to lock the door, **yet** every time I
>   come home, it's locked.

Note that "still" can replace "yet" here with the same meaning.

Comment: Why we can't use still in the question sentences?

Comment: You can use still in questions, but it has a different meaning - it ask whether a situation continues to be in force: Are you still living in New York? (=is this the case even now?) -versus- Are you living in New York yet? (=have you followed through with your plans to move there already)

Answer (score 5):

Offhand I can only think of one specific context where ***yet*** can't in principle be replaced by ***still***...

> 1: *"Do you love me still?"*
>    2: *"Do you love me yet?"*

...where the natural implication of #1 is *"You loved me before. Has the situation changed?"*, but for #2 it's *"You **did not** love me. Has the situation changed?*"*. Note that in practice most native speakers would put ***still*** before rather than after the verb, but grammatically both words can go in either position.

Apart from that, I think you can probably always use ***still*** instead of ***yet***. So for simplicity I suggest you *only* use ***yet*** in contexts such as the above (where the focus is on a *possible future having arrived*, rather than an actual past condition which may no longer apply). That's to say - don't use ***yet*** in other contexts, even if theoretically it would be equivalent to ***still*** (in what's usually a formal/dated/literary [register](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/registerterm.htm)).

Closely related is the conjunction ***but***, which can often be replaced by ***yet*** or ***still***. My advice would be to use ***but*** whenever a "contrastive conjunction" is required (i.e. - as above, avoid ***yet*** if you don't *need* it).

---

TL;DR: You *can* say *"The plan could **yet** succeed"*, but you probably don't want to. *"The plan could **still** succeed"* is more "natural" English today, particularly in *spoken* contexts (but it's not "informal").

Comment: I think "Do you yet love me?" would have the same meaning as "Do you love me still?", even though it sounds a little awkward.

Comment: @Ataraxia: Perhaps I haven't explained myself very well. Rest assured almost no native speaker alive today would ever ask *"Do you yet love me?"*. It's hopelessly dated/literary.

Comment: I know, I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Ataraxia: Hmm. The entire *point* of my answer was to convey that such usage is ***not*** worth bothering with.

Comment: I know. That's why I just mentioned it in the comments and didn't suggest that you add it to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yet synonyms:

> - even though
> - though
> - however
> - nevertheless

Still synonyms:

> - even
> - nevertheless
> - though
> - after all

synonyms from [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/still)and [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/yet).

Sorry, I can't answer your question when to use it, can you please give an example? I will edit my answer.

Comment: Actually my problem is the usage of them in the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Still can also mean 'not moving', so one meaning of still is a near-synonym [same meaning] of yet, but other definitions of still take on other meanings.  Sometimes still can be used for peaceful, as in "The forest was peaceful" [compare with the "The forest was still"]