# He has been working on the problem for a long time but is still/yet not able to solve it

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, polarity-items

Sentence improvement:

> He has been working on the problem for a long time but is still not able to solve it.

I believe this sentence is correct. But the answer to of this question is to place *yet* in place of *still*. Any suggestions on this please.

Comment: There are two viable options:
1. *He has been working on the problem for a long time but is still not able to solve it.*
2. *He has been working on the problem for a long time but is (still) yet to solve it.*

Comment: You might want to refer to this ELL post: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30084/what-is-the-difference-between-yet-and-still

Comment: Also, note that in some dialects of English, the meanings of "yet" and "still" are slightly different, so you might read a sentence like "Is your father alive yet?" which is completely acceptable in that dialect.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think these are improvements (since both are longer), but these are also common ways of saying it.

> He has been working on the problem for a long time but has not able to solve it yet.

or

> He has been working on the problem for a long time but has not yet been able to solve it.

Comment: The first option should be "...not *been* able to..."